# Do you need to blank out the Id field after a failed insert?

Tags: apex

I have read in the documentation that after a failed insert the Id will need to be blanked out so that further errors aren't thrown when you try to insert the record again. But if I run an anonymous script with:

`Account acc = new Account();
try{
    insert acc;
}catch(Exception e){
    System.debug(acc.Id);
}`

then the output of this is null so it seems that you don't need to blank out the Id or am I missing something?

Comment: Where in the documentation (and what documentation) did you read that?

Comment: Instead of talking about a general thing you've read somewhere, can you provide an example of something you're trying to do?

Comment: Please see the guidelines for [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be referring to [Transaction Control](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_transaction_control.htm):

> - The ID on an sObject inserted after setting a savepoint is not cleared after a rollback. Create an sObject to insert after a rollback. Attempting to insert the sObject using the variable created before the rollback fails because the sObject variable has an ID. Updating or upserting the sObject using the same variable also fails because the sObject is not in the database and, thus, cannot be updated.

The scenario where you need to unset the `Id` is when your insert succeeds, but the transaction is rolled back.

```
Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
try
{
    insert validRecord;
    insert invalidRecord;
}
catch (DmlException e)
{
    Database.rollback(sp);
    system.assertNotEquals(null, validRecord.Id);
    system.assertEquals(null, invalidRecord.Id);
}
```

If you want to try to insert `validRecord` again, you need to set its `Id` to `null`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no actual record to get if the insert fails, and no ID available as the record was never created. What you can do is loop through the resultset, and look at other attributes of your records. The List you are inserting will be in the same order as the resultset. So, you could do something like this:

```
List<Account> accountList = new List<Account>();
Account acc1 = new Account(Name = 'Test Acc');
Account acc2 = new Account(Name = '');
accountList.add(acc1);
accountList.add(acc2);
Database.SaveResult[] saveResultSet = Database.insert(accs, False);
System.debug('saveResultSet: ' + saveResultSet);
System.debug('accountList: ' + accountList);

for(Integer i=0;i<saveResultSet.size();i++){
    if(!SR[i].isSuccess()){//only look at failures, or NOT Successes
      system.debug(saveResultSet[i]. getErrors()));
      system.debug(accountList[i]);
    }
}
```

[See SaveResult class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database_saveresult.htm)